# Как менять размер сцены

Tags: xcode, swift, spritekit

Как сделать, чтобы размер сцены в игре на spritekit менялся сведением и разведение пальцев (так как меняется размер карты, фотографий или игр-деревень типа клеш оф кланс), а так же как реализовать передвижение по этой сцене при помощи скольжения пальцем по экрану.

Например, я увеличил сцену до определенного масштаба, затем мне надо как-то передвигаться на оставшуюся за экраном невидимую часть.

Где об этом может быть написано?
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

можно добавить камеру [SKCameraNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcameranode) к сцене и маштабироват/ двигать только ее, тогда должно нормально получится